# How to get a Double instead of a double when parseing a String?

Tags: java, parsing, double

I'm trying to parse a `String` into a `Double` and due to restrictions on variables I have to do it in a very odd way. Currently I am having the issue of having two functions both named the same, but one takes a `Double` and the other a `double`.

```
    public class Calculator {
            Double x;

            public Double x(String x){
                //code ommited 
                x(Double.parseDouble(x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1, x.length())));
                //^^ attempting to get this variable to be a Double instead of double

                return new Double(x);
            }

            public Double x(Double x){
                //code ommited
                return new Double(0);
            }


            public Double x(double x){
                //code ommited 
                return new Double(0);
            }

    }
```

Comment: `new Double(String)` will convert a `String` to a `Double` object.

Comment: Doesn't Java support auto wrapping and unwrapping? Passing a double should work in place of a Double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `Double.parseDouble`, use `Double.valueOf(String)`, which return a Double.

BTW, using `Double.valueOf(String)` is equivalent to `new Double(Double.parseDouble(String))`.